# Trigger change function and set the value of select in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi I am having given code

```
$('#filled-in-box2').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#filled-in-box2').is(':checked')) {
        $('select#employee_permanent_address_attributes_country').val($('select#employee_contact_attributes_country').val()).change();
      $('select#permanent_address_state_code').val($('select#contact_state_code').val());
    }
});
```

So I want after change function or when change function trigger at that time only **permanent_address_state_code** value will set same as **contact_state_code value**.
I have tried this code too but its not working

```
$('#filled-in-box2').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#filled-in-box2').is(':checked')) {
        $('select#employee_permanent_address_attributes_country').val($('select#employee_contact_attributes_country').val()).trigger('change',function(){
            $('select#permanent_address_state_code').val($('select#contact_state_code').val());
        });

    }
  });
```

I am attachiing snapshot when click on check box it does not populate state 
[image]

Please guide me how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are SELECTS not checkboxes. Thats one of the reasons your code does not work. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-dynamically-select-option-in-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#filled-in-box2').on('click', function () {
   if ($('#filled-in-box2').is(':checked')) {                           $('select#employee_permanent_address_attributes_country').val($('select#employee_contact_attributes_country').val());
    $('select#permanent_address_state_code').val($('select#contact_state_code').val()); 
 }
 });
```

This alone will work for your requirement to change permanent state and country when you click on checkbox.